# Using an updated Path() to draw new lines on Scene

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to javafx and was using it to carry out a version of the Ant Colony Optimization algorithm. I have written some code that was supposed to display a small circle as the ant which moves about randomly in the plane. This worked fine. But I could not modify the code to display the path of the ant on the scene. Basically I want the path of the ant to be highlighted by lines as the ant moves on a 2D plane.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Random;

//Line can either be a sound or a shape

import javafx.animation.Animation.Status;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import java.lang.Object;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class TestMotion extends Application {

    int N = 10;
    static ArrayList<Integer> move = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private double sceneWidth = 512;
    private double sceneHeight = 512;
    MyNode node = new MyNode(0,0,5);
    Path pathA = new Path();

    int n = 10;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Group root = new Group();

        root.getChildren().addAll(node, pathA);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        animate();

    }

    //convention conversion (i,j) to node number x
    public static int convert(int i, int j, int N)
    {
        return (j*N +i+1);
    }

    //convention conversion node number x to (i,j)
    //implement in order of definition
    public static int reconvertY(int x, int N)
    {
        return  (int) java.lang.Math.floor((x-1)/N);
    }

    public static int reconvertX(int x, int N, int j)
    {
        return  (x-j*N-1);
    }

    private void animate() {

        nextPos(move, N);
        int y1 = reconvertY(move.get(move.size()-1), N);
        int x1 = reconvertX(move.get(move.size()-1), N, y1);
        MyNode here = new MyNode(10*x1, 10*y1, 1);

        System.out.println(move.get(move.size()-1));

        pathA.getElements().add (new MoveTo ( node.getTranslateX() + node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0, node.getTranslateY() + node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));
        pathA.getElements().add (new LineTo( here.getTranslateX() + here.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0, here.getTranslateY() + here.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));
        pathA.setStroke(Color.RED);
        pathA.setStrokeWidth(1.0);

        PathTransition pathTransitionA = new PathTransition(); 
        pathTransitionA.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
        pathTransitionA.setNode(node);
        pathTransitionA.setPath(pathA);


        pathTransitionA.play();
        pathA = new Path();
        pathTransitionA.setOnFinished( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                if( pathTransitionA.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING)
                    {return;}

                animate();
            }
        });


    }
    //allot new node to the arraylist such that it is adjacent to the previously assigned node
    private void nextPos(ArrayList<Integer> array, int N)
    {
        //I removed this part to save space because it is probably irrelevant the the problem at hand

    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {


         move.add(1);
         launch(args);
     }

     public static class MyNode extends StackPane {

         public MyNode(double x, double y, double r) {

             // create circle
             Circle circle = new Circle();
             circle.setRadius(r);

             circle.setFill(Color.BLUE);

             // set position
             setTranslateX( x);
             setTranslateY( y);

             getChildren().add(circle);

         }



}


}
```

On execution the scene displays the path for the first step only and then stops displaying the path altogether. I cannot figure out why. The `path` is renewed each time the `animate()` function runs, and both `node` and `here` should be updated regularly. So shouldn't each iteration display the newest path segment of the ant?

Can someone please explain the problem? Is it not possible to exploit `Path()` and `PathTransition()` to display these segments and avoid using `Line()`?

Comment: If I remove the line pathA = new Path() from the animate function, then the ant doesn't move from it's previous position to the current position, but actually moves all the way from the origin to the current position. In this case however, the path is updated as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not wrong. Only the problem is whenever you are calling the `animate()`, the path formed is having the coordinates as before. The path coordinates are always returning the following

```
1.0, 1.0 for moveTo and 5.0,5.0 for LineTo
```

You need to pass fresh coordinates each time as that the `path` becomes a new one. Also to keep showing the old path along with the new one, you need to keep adding the newly created `path` to the `Group`.

Here's what I have changed in you code. Have a look.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.animation.Animation.Status;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TestMotion extends Application {

    int N = 10;
    static ArrayList<Integer> move = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private double sceneWidth = 512;
    private double sceneHeight = 512;
    MyNode node = new MyNode(0, 0, 5);
    Group root; //Made root as global variable
    int n = 10;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        root = new Group();

        root.getChildren().addAll(node);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        animate(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f); //Passing initial coordinates to the method

    }

    //convention conversion (i,j) to node number x
    public static int convert(int i, int j, int N) {
        return (j * N + i + 1);
    }

    //convention conversion node number x to (i,j)
    //implement in order of definition
    public static int reconvertY(int x, int N) {
        return (int) java.lang.Math.floor((x - 1) / N);
    }

    public static int reconvertX(int x, int N, int j) {
        return (x - j * N - 1);
    }

    private void animate(float moveX, float moveY, float lineX, float lineY) {
        Path pathA = new Path();
        root.getChildren().add(pathA);
        nextPos(move, N);
        int y1 = reconvertY(move.get(move.size() - 1), N);
        int x1 = reconvertX(move.get(move.size() - 1), N, y1);
        //Applying coordinates as obtained
        pathA.getElements().add(new MoveTo(moveX, moveY)); 
        pathA.getElements().add(new LineTo(lineX, lineY));
        pathA.setStroke(Color.RED);
        pathA.setStrokeWidth(1.0);

        PathTransition pathTransitionA = new PathTransition();
        pathTransitionA.setDuration(Duration.millis(100));
        pathTransitionA.setNode(node);
        pathTransitionA.setPath(pathA);

        pathTransitionA.play();

        pathTransitionA.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                if (pathTransitionA.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
                    return;
                }

                animate(lineX, lineY, lineX + 2, lineY + 2); //previous path's endpoint makes the start point of the new Path
            }
        });

    }

    //allot new node to the arraylist such that it is adjacent to the previously assigned node
    private void nextPos(ArrayList<Integer> array, int N) {
        //I removed this part to save space because it is probably irrelevant the the problem at hand

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        move.add(1);
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class MyNode extends StackPane {

        public MyNode(double x, double y, double r) {

            // create circle
            Circle circle = new Circle();
            circle.setRadius(r);

            circle.setFill(Color.BLUE);

            // set position
            setTranslateX(x);
            setTranslateY(y);

            getChildren().add(circle);

        }

    }

}
```

Hope It helps.

Comment: I didn't initialize the animate function because it says it can't take double values. But even then I made the rest of the changes you made and it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why can't it take double values?

Comment: Oh I didn't change the function definition. Sorry. I was still using my version of  PathTransition. I made root a global node and added pathA to it in the animate function. That solved the problem. But your code is much cleaner anyway so that's what I'm going to use.